# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o8484.showString

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to run the following code on a huge data set:

```
df.replace(JobAbbreviation, subset = ['title']).show()
```

And I get this error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o8484.showString. :
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped
> SparkContext. This stopped SparkContext was created at:

Comment: Your spark context was broken. You need to restart the spark session

Comment: I did but I get the same error. should I restart kernel?

Comment: yes that should help